# Different packages in android.jar from maven central and from android sdk

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I found a android.jar here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android
What's in it are 
`android
assets
con.android.internal.util
dalvik
res
AndroidManifest.xml
resources.arsc`

In android sdk installed on my computer there's android.jar in path Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar, but in this Jar there are some extra packages

```
java
javax
junit
org
```

My question is why this android.jar has extra packages than the one on maven central? I think these extra jars are causing errors when I try to build my project.

Error detail

```
Error1: Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task':MyAndroidProject:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExceptionorg.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: do you want to paste your gradle ?

Comment: the only difference is how I'm referencing this jar:
`compile name: 'android.jar'`
or
`compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'`